# How to restrict azure blob container creation using SAS

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage

How to set permission to not create container, while generating Account SAS token? Here is my settings.

```
    // Create a new access policy for the account.
    SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write,
        Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob | SharedAccessAccountServices.Table,
        ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2),
        Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOrHttp
    };
```

Comment: Can you also include what permissions you do want in your account SAS?

Comment: I have two webapi one for admin and one for normal users.
I have a storage account that can contain many different containers for many users i.e have a container per user. I require the following permissions:

Permission for Admin: Create, Delete containers
     List blobs in a container
     
Permission for Users: Read, write , delete blobs to their respective container,
restrict container create
      
     
I am tryin to create two separate Account SAS to achieve the above? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

Given that you have multiple containers, the account SAS is a good option. You'll need one for the admin and one for the user.

Here's an example of how to create the admin SAS:

```
// Create a new access policy for the account.
SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
{
    // SAS for Blob service only.
    Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,

    // Admin has read, write, list, and delete permissions on all containers.
    // In order to write blobs, Object resource type must also be specified.
    ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,

    Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | 
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write |
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create | 
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List | 
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Delete,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
    Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
};
```

And here's an example of how to create the user SAS:

```
// Create a new access policy for the account.
SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
{
    // SAS for Blob service only.
    Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,

    // User has create, read, write, and delete permissions on blobs.
    ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,

    Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read |
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write |
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create |
        SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Delete,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
    Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
};
```

Original answer:

You definitely need to use an account SAS for the admin SAS, but you should be able to use a service SAS on the container for the user SAS, unless you have a need for an account SAS that I am not understanding from your question. It's probably better to use the service SAS when you can so that you can use the least complicated permissions. Also, you can use a stored access policy with the service SAS, which we recommend as a best practice so that it's easy to revoke the SAS if it were ever compromised.

With the service SAS, you don't need a permission to restrict container creation, because the service SAS doesn't allow you to create a container in the first place.

Here's code to create the service SAS on the container, including the stored access policy:

```
        // Create the storage account with the connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client object.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Get a reference to the container for which shared access signature will be created.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Create blob container permissions, consisting of a shared access policy 
        // and a public access setting. 
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = container.GetPermissions();

        // Clear the container's shared access policies to avoid naming conflicts if you run this method more than once.
        //blobPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Clear();

        // The shared access policy provides 
        // read/write access to the container for 24 hours.
        containerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            // To ensure SAS is valid immediately, don’t set start time.
            // This way, you can avoid failures caused by small clock differences.
            // Note that the Create permission allows the user to create a new blob, as does Write.
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |
               SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete
        });

        // The public access setting explicitly specifies that 
        // the container is private, so that it can't be accessed anonymously.
        containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off;

        // Set the permission policy on the container.
        container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);

        // Get the shared access signature to share with users.
        string sasToken =
           container.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "mypolicy");
```

Take a look at the examples shown here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#examples-create-and-use-shared-access-signatures.

Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt584140.aspx.

Let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Many thanks. Because admin will be creating many containers, i.e container per user, not sure whether to go for Service SAS on each containers. Because if i have 100 containers, then i had to create 100 Service SAS Uri.
Sorry if i am wrong.
That is the reason i was thinking of having account SAS. Please let me know if there is better solution.

Comment: Ultimately i am looking the below thing:
1. As mentioned there are two webapi one for User and one for Admin
2. User should be able to Download, Upload, Update, Delete blobs. (User shouldn't have container create permission.)
3. Admin should be able to Create container, List blobs in container, Delete container.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can create two account SAS for your scenario: one for the admin and one for the user. I will update my answer to show examples for both.

Comment: Thank you.an example for my scenario would be of great help. Thank you

Comment: Than you very much for updating your answer with example

Comment: To add the table service, can we add the Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Table ? As both admin and user has to write to add audit table.